# Sort by order of values in a select statement “in” clause in oracle

Tags: oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

```
select * 
  from table 
 where column in ('value3', 'value1', 'value2');
```

So I want the output to be in the same sequence as that of the values in the "IN" of the above qry.

```
output
-------
value3
value1
value2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to write a custom `ORDER BY` clause.  Something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE column_name IN ('v3', 'v1', 'v2' )
 ORDER BY (CASE column_name
                WHEN 'v3' THEN 1
                WHEN 'v1' THEN 2
                WHEN 'v2' THEN 3
                ELSE 4
            END) asc
```

Comment: it worked, thanks. just wondering what can be done in case of many values

Comment: What if in the IN clause I would have 100 elements? How can I make that order by to be dynamic?